# Is "vegetable base" a common term in English?

Tags: word-request

How do they refer to big roofed places, in which vegetables, having been brought from fields, are kept before being taken to various outlets to be sold?

I thought "vegetable base" was a good term, but it looks like Google doesn't return many results. Besides, Wikipedia doesn't have an article on "vegetable base"

Comment: "vegetable center" would possibly work OK as a general term.  Note that there are various specific actual terms, depending on what you mean.  Example "vegetable warehouse"  "vegetable distribution center"  "vegetable packing plant"  "vegetable sorting house" "vegetable storehouse" and so on.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Vegetable base** doesn't work in this context. You would use **vegetable base** to mean that some product comprised mainly vegetables as in: Our soup has a vegetable base.

Your options are several. Supermarkets store fruits and vegetables in refrigerated warehouses. Individual sections of these warehouses are referred to as storerooms (or sometimes as cool-rooms if kept at low temperature). Such storage centres may be referred to as depots or distribution centres although these words are used for any base away from the hypermarkets/supermarkets they serve.

Farmers keep products in barns (which are big) or sheds (which are small) prior to dispatch. Products stored in rooms underground are kept in cellars.

People keep fruit and vegetables in their pantries unless they need to be kept cool in refrigerators or frozen in freezers.

But the short answer to your question is either **warehouses** (which are large and may be refrigerated) or **storerooms** (which are relatively small).

Comment: Large-scale fruit & vegetable farmers don't (at least in my experience) refer to the buildings in which they store produce as barns.  They might be warehouses, or cold-storage facilities.  (But often the grower will not store the produce, but will ship it direct from the field.)  Barns are mostly for livestock or machinery.

Comment: Some "sheds" are very big.  The terms use seems to vary a lot around the UK at least.  Possibly a "shed" is less weather tight than a "barn"?  Only basing that on cattle sheds often being relatively airy although still very large.

Comment: Vegetable base doesn't return any Google results because the only soup that is, that I can think of, is split pea.  Which has to be based from ham stock anyway,  otherwise it's terrible.

Comment: @Mazura How about the following: https://www.betterthanbouillon.com/products/seasoned-vegetable-base/                                   https://www.splendidtable.org/recipes/vegetable-broth-base                                                                   https://www.epicurious.com/recipes/member/views/vegetable-base-50010739              https://foodinjars.com/recipe/homemade-vegetable-soup-base/

Answer (score 9):

The term "Vegetable Base" would be construed to describe a food where a vegetable is the primary constituent - such as a "Vegetable Based Soup Stock".  The "Vegetable Base" would be the vegetable component, and would usually (although not always) be a concentrate of some sort.

You're referring to a "cold storage facility", in this case, specifically for vegetables, although the same terminology is used for storing processed and semi-processed meat animals (eg sides of beef, etc.).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 8):

The terms [packing house](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_house) or [packhouse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/packhouse) describe a structure similar to what you are looking for.

> A **packing house** is a facility where fruit is received and processed prior to distribution to market.  (Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_house))

Some sources refer specifically to fruit packing or alternatively for meat processing (where is is also called a *slaughterhouse*), while others (e.g. see [Wiktionary entry](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/packhouse)) include other kinds of produce as well.

Wikipedia has [a list packing houses in the United States](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_packing_houses),  and most of them have "packing house" as part of the name. This seems to indicate ithat the term is established in the food industry.

Comment: You should include any useful supporting information (such as a relevant quote) in the answer itself, so that if the linked page changes or moves, the answer will remain useful.

Comment: I don't expect the Wikipedia entry to change or move, but for possible ease of reference I added a quote too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia uses the generic term "produce distribution centre"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontario_Food_Terminal). "Produce" is a common and highly standardized term for unprocessed fruits and vegetables on their way to retail. Here in Ontario we have installations called "food terminals", where produce is sold at wholesale to buyers working for restaurants and markets. But "produce distribution center" is probably the better generic option.

With "warehouse" the emphasis is on storage, possibly long-term (which would not be the case for produce) and also does not convey the multi-buyer wholesale distribution aspect.

Comment: "food terminal" sounds very nice. Is it only specific to Ontario?

Comment: But note that a "distribution center" is totally different from a "farmer's packing shed" or a "vegetable packing center".

Comment: "Food terminal" does seem to be only what Ontario calls it; I can't get any Google results for anywhere else. So yeah, it's local. And yes, I read the OP's question as being more about a waypoint for fresh produce being distributed to markets; not about packing or canning or freezing or processing. I believe for those channels, the produce goes straight from the farm to the respective plant. You'd call those places "processing centers" or "packing plant" or "cannery", etc.

Answer (score 1):

While not vegetables, grain is stored in a **granary**.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/89134)

Comment: He was asking about terms used for buildings used to store produce, so I gave him one.

Comment: It's a good answer.

Answer (score -3):

That would be called a [silo](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/silo). As others have said, the term "base" with the modifier "vegetable" refers to a soup or another dish that is created starting from vegetables.

Comment: No. A silo is a round, tower-like structure used to store silaage tps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silage that's generally used for animal feed.  This is a classic farm silo: https://www.dreamstime.com/stock-images-classic-vermont-farm-winter-scene-white-silo-red-barn-image29903064

Comment: @jamesqf, at least in American English, a "silo" is also used to store grain and other powder-like substances (sawdust, cement, etc.).  Produce wouldn't be stored in a silo.

Comment: silos are usually for wheat.  less commonly for "silage".

Comment: @Mark: I disagree, but perhaps it's a regional usage?  Where I grew up, the round structure next to your barn was a silo, and used only for silage - note the similarity of the words?  The only other usage I've seen for silo is an underground missle facility.  A tower-like structure used for storing grain is called a grain elevator.